# Easily check if table exists with python, sqlalchemy on an sql database

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

Hello I am using sqlalchemy and pandas to process some data and then save everything to a table in an sql database. I am trying to find a quick easy and standardized way to check if a table exists in a database based on a table name.

I have found the `has_table()` function but no working examples. Does anyone has something like  give "engine connection" & "table name"-> return true or false if table exists

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With SQLAlchemy 1.4+ you can call `has_table` by using an `inspect` object, like so:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# … 

engine = sa.create_engine(connection_uri)
insp = sa.inspect(engine)
print(insp.has_table("team", schema="dbo"))  # True (or False, as the case may be)
```

For earlier versions of SQLAlchemy, see the other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64862306/2144390).

Comment: that is almost correct I tested it but it didnt run for me I dont know why I had to add insp.dialect.has_table.

Comment: What dialect are you using? The above works for me with `mssql+pyodbc`.

Comment: could it be different versions of the library? because the inspector object does not have a has_table funtion at all

Comment: My apologies. I was testing against the version 1.4 code base. BTW, 1.4 is in public beta now; check it out!

Comment: To which value I have to set the schema parameter in the method has_table if the table has no schema name?

Comment: @Freude - The `schema=` keyword argument defaults to `None` so you can simply omit it.

Comment: This also works for the version 2.0 engine.

Answer (score 4):

so I made this function based on this idea from the first reposnse:

```
def table_exists(engine,name):
    ins = inspect(engine)
    ret =ins.dialect.has_table(engine.connect(),name)
    print('Table "{}" exists: {}'.format(name, ret))
    return ret
```

Answer (score -1):

For SQLAlchemy==2.0.25

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

url = URL.create(drivername=drivername,
                              username=youruser,
                              password=yourpass,
                              host=yourhost,
                              database=yourdbname)

engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)

if engine.dialect.has_table(table_name=YOURTABLENAME,connection=engine.connect()):
    echo "table exist"
```

Comment: Using this method is [explicitly discouraged](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/internals.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Dialect.has_table) in the docs: "This method is used internally by SQLAlchemy, and is published so that third-party dialects may provide an implementation. It is not the public API for checking for table presence. Please use the Inspector.has_table() method."